# X.509 Certificates gui program in java

Tags: java, user-interface, digital-certificate

i am a student and i have an assignment to do which involves Digital Certificates.I literally know very little about this topic and my project that i have to do is:"Create a GUI program(System) that authenticates users based on their digital certificate" .Now, That's the whole project request , and i looked a little(too much i must say) and literally found  nothing that could help me .Researching i found out that the most basic certificate is X.509, so i d like to write a simple maybe java gui program that could solve my problem, if someone can help me , please do! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know how certificate based authentication works, here is some information you shall need to read.
https://www.networkworld.com/article/2226498/infrastructure/infrastructure-management-simply-put-how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work.html

You should discuss with the person where assignment originated what sort of UI they expect and how the client would send the certificate to the server for authentication.

X.509 is a specification. All certificates conform to the specification to ensure that systems can work with each others certs. However you can maintain the certificates in many different formats.

A real life use case of this could be a terminal program that sends your personal key to the server and the server program opens up a session for you.